# Apache Server Status

Tags: apache, http, centos

Out of interest, I wanted to view some apache stats on my server. A quick google revealed status_mod. I jumped over to my httpd.conf file, and uncommenting the following lines (editing to my domain):

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from .mydomain.com
</Location>
```

However I am presented with 404 error. A bit of research suggest something about having multiple domains in your vhost causing the issue, however I never really found a definitive solution or answer?

Comment: Are you sure mod_status is actually loaded in your config?

Comment: yep, I have LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so in there

Comment: how about if you changed `Allow from .mydomain.com` to `Allow from localhost`? or try to add this `Location` configuration to your `VirtualHost`.